# Incorrect Pri Eitz Chaim?

Tags: torah-study, gematria-numerology

I have reviewed [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Etz_Chaim%2C_Gate_of_The_New_Month%2C_Chanukah%2C_and_Purim.6.36?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%20%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95%2C%20%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%2C%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%98%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9C%2C%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%9D%20%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9%3A) Pri Eitz Chaim multiple times, and it seems that the gematria does not add up correctly.

Here is the text.

כבוד  מלכותו  ואת  יקר  תפארת  גדולתו,  גימטריא  אלה בגדי כהן גדול, מכנסים כתונת מצנפת ואבנט חשן ואפוד ומעיל, והוא מוסכם עם המדרש:

Comment: What does not add up, gematria?

Comment: How about אלה בגדי כהן גדול מכנסים כתונת מצנפת אבנט חשן אפוד מעיל ציץ

Comment: @shmosel that is significantly better, its off by 1. Maybe you can squeeze an aleph in there?

Comment: @shmosel - thought of that too! I wondered why the tzitz was left out - that takes it above the calculation. Currently כבוד מלכותו ואת יקר תפארת גדולתו amounts to 2,781 and אלה בגדי כהן גדול, מכנסים כתונת מצנפת ואבנט חשן ואפוד ומעיל is 2608? Tzitz is 190 which makes it 2798?

Comment: @TheTargum where did I go wrong with my math?

Comment: My gut feeling is that it was probably an error with sefaria. Where can i find this Pri Eitz Chaim in a sefer on HebrewBooks? i think that will be more authoritative.

Comment: The 5564 and 5721 editions are consistent with Sefaria's version. I couldn't find it in the 5542 edition. Maybe reach out to the purchaser of this manuscript: https://www.genazym.com/auction/606-genazym-7-prime/lot-55-7/

Comment: It's consistent see here - https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14173&st=&pgnum=106&hilite= right side, 3rd paragraph?

Comment: Also consistent with this one - https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/153462/p/108/t/0.30459976941190561234/fs/kRzoQ0qBl07R90IQZx2jtV4w80G4byC9UYnuXTvi2Dhx/start/0/end/3/c

Answer (score 3):

The small sum gematria of: כבוד מלכותו ואת יקר תפארת גדולתו is 100 (14 plus 25 plus 11 plus 4 plus 19 plus 27). When including the 27 letters, 6 words and kollel that brings the total to: 134.

The small sum gematria of: מכנסים כתונת מצנפת אבנט חשן אפוד מעיל, the garments of the Kohen Gadol that are listed is 135.

It's worth noting that the *Tzitz* is not being included in the count as one of the garments. What the Pri Eitz Chaim is trying to emphasize from that requires additional reflection. Generally, eight garments is the number associated with the Kohen Gadol.

As pointed out in the comment of Shmosel, if the Tzitz is added:
אלה בגדי כהן גדול מכנסים כתונת מצנפת אבנט חשן אפוד מעיל ציץ, then the plain gematria 2,780 is one away from the plain gematria of:
כבוד מלכותו ואת יקר תפארת גדולתו, which is 2781. This gematria seems to allude to the closing words of Jeremiah 31:13 which are:
וְהָפַכְתִּ֨י אֶבְלָ֤ם לְשָׂשׂוֹן֙ וְנִ֣חַמְתִּ֔ים וְשִׂמַּחְתִּ֖ים מִיגוֹנָֽם

In general, when calculating gematria values, values within one of each other are considered the same.

When reading the text of Pri Eitz Chaim, one needs to be careful not to take the text word for word literally, but to reflect on the message of what is being said.

Comment: Thanks @Yaacov can you explain the maths more pls?

Comment: @Dov What do you not understand?

Comment: How you got 100?

Comment: @Dov More clear now? "Small Sum Gematria" מספר קטן.

Comment: Note that I removed the vav prefixes.

Comment: @shmosel So did I. That’s obvious. That is a clue as to how to treat the text from Pri Eitz Chaim. FYI, the Mispar Katan (135) also seems to allude to (י״ט כסלו), the Rosh HaShanah of Chassidut which is mentioned by the Rishon of France in שאלות ותשובות מן השמים.